# Rewrite code into classes using object-oriented programming (OOP)

Tags: javascript

I made a rating as in the author's video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dsRJTxieD4U

```js
const rateStars = document.querySelectorAll('.js-rate');
rateStars.forEach((rateStar, clickedIdx) => {
  rateStar.addEventListener('click', () => {
    rateStars.forEach((otherRateStar, otherIdx) => {
      if (otherIdx <= clickedIdx) {
        otherRateStar.classList.add('rate__item_active');
      };
    });
  });
});
```

Everything works perfectly, but my task is to create a js-class (OOP)

[image]

```
  //rate.pug

mixin rate(params = {})
  -
    const {
      rating= "",
    } = params;
    let i = 0;


  .rate
    ul.rate__list
      while i < 5
        if (i < rating)
          li.rate__item(class= "js-rate rate__item_active")
        else
          li.rate__item(class= "js-rate")
        - i++
```

I got the following code structure:

```js
// index.js
import Rate from './Rate';
const rateStars = document.querySelectorAll('js-rate');
rateStars.forEach((rateStar, clickedIdx) => new Rate(rateStar, clickedIdx));
        
// Rate.js
class Rate {
  constructor(rateStar, clickedIdx) {
    this.rateStar = rateStar;
    this.clickedIdx = clickedIdx;
    this.bindEventListeners();
  }

  bindEventListeners() {
    this.rateStar.addEventListener('click', this.handleRateClick.bind(this));
  }
      
  handleRateClick() {
    this.rateStar.classList.add('rate__item_active');
  }
}

export default Rate;
```

However, I have no idea how to proceed from here.
Sorry I'm a complete noob. This is my first time asking a question here.
the task is complicated by the fact that you need to place several ratings on one page.I write some mixins:
[image]

When there are several ratings on the page, then the stars are added to all the ratings.

1)this is the default state

[image]

2. After click

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to rewrite code in classes? Functional programming is preferred in Javascript.

Comment: @Aditya 
according to Airbnb JavaScript Style Guide: https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#classes--constructors

Comment: @Aysur "*Always use class.*" means "Always use `class` syntax **when writing a class** (constructor + prototype)". You aren't, and you don't need to.

Comment: @Bergi 
I understand, but this is required by my mentor

Comment: @Aysur Then you should ask your mentor. Using a class and creating instances doesn't really make sense here.

Comment: @Bergi ok, I didn't write the code using the class. But I have a new problem: when there are several ratings on the page, then the stars are added to all the ratings

Comment: @Aysur Can you show your DOM structure, please? How do you distinguish which stars belong to which rating?

Comment: @Bergi I completely rewrote my question and also added pictures

Comment: Ah, thanks. You shouldn't do `document.querySelectorAll('.js-rate');` but `document.querySelectorAll('ul.rate__list');`, only then for each list do `rateList.querySelectorAll('.js-rate')` (or just `rateList.children`) and take those as the `(other)rateStars` in your click handler

Comment: @Bergi Unfortunately, I don't quite understand what you are talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem of your change to class, is that you're not adding `rate__item_active` to the previous stars as you're doing in the first code example.

So for your class to work like the first code example, this is how you should do it:

```js
// index.js
import Rate from './Rate';
rateStars.forEach((rateStar, index) => new Rate(rateStar, index, rateStars));
    
// Rate.js
class Rate {
  constructor(rateStar, index, rateStars) {
    this.rateStar = rateStar;
    this.clickedIdx = index;
    this.rateStars = rateStars;
    this.bindEventListeners();
  }

  bindEventListeners() {
    this.rateStar.addEventListener('click', this.handleRateClick.bind(this));
  }
  
  handleRateClick() {
    for(let i = 0; i <= this.clickedIdx; i++) {
      this.rateStars[i].classList.add('rate__item_active');
    }
  }
}

export default Rate;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works! But I have a new problem: when there are multiple ratings on a page, the stars are added to all the ratings on the page

Comment: That's because you are retrieving all the of the ratings when you call `document.querySelectorAll('.js-rate')`. You need to have some sort of unique identifier on each group of ratings instead of everyone having `'.js-rate'`. Are you using a framework for your project?

Comment: No, only Pug, js native and Sass with Webpack.  I completely rewrote my question and also added pictures